# Cloudflare page rule to exclude desired PHP file

Tags: php, cloudflare

I am trying to create a new page rule in Cloudflare so my file `file.php?id=` can bypass any security or browser checker.

Not sure if this works:

```
*site.com/file. *
```

Comment: Is this not a question for the CloudFlare support ?

Comment: no they dont respond

Comment: Well that's their problem... and yours. You are using a FREE or PAID Package ? Anyway.... CloudFlare is NGINX, so *site.com/file.* will NOT work. You can exclude paths like /login or /forums, but not file extensions ( and least from what I know ).

Comment: I am using free package, huh thats really bad. because i have API callback to that file. Any idea?

Comment: Not really, because everything is behind NGINX proxy, so it is really hard for you to manipulate...